# dynatree not working in a zend form

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, zend-form, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

im trying to add a dynatree to a zend form, i managed to implement dynatree in an normal page in my zend project..ive added the code necessary to the html to show the dynatree, but it still doesnt show.
so in my page ive got a button to call the add form.
here is the code 
/tags/add

```
 public function addAction()
{
    // action body
      $this->_helper->layout()->setLayout('form-adr');
    $form = new Application_Form_Tags();

    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

Code for layout form_adr

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/theme/style/reset.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/theme/style/root.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/theme/style/grid.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/theme/style/typography.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/theme/style/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/theme/style/jquery-plugin-base.css" />
     <!--dynatree-->

<script src='/dynatree/jquery/jquery.cookie.js' type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/dynatree/src/skin/ui.dynatree.css'>
<script src='/dynatree/src/jquery.dynatree.js' type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body style="background:#fff;">

    <!--CONTENT-->
    <?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
    <!--//CONTENT-->

</body>
</html>
```

code for Application_Form_Tags

```
class Application_Form_Tags extends Zend_Form
{

public function init()
{
    /* Form Elements & Other Definitions Here ... */
       $name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('nome');
    $name->setAttrib('class', 'st-forminput');
    $name->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
    $name->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');
    $name->removeDecorator('Label');

     $descricao = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('descricao');
    $descricao->setAttrib('class', 'st-forminput');
    $descricao->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
    $descricao->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');
    $descricao->removeDecorator('Label');

    $modo = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('modo');$modo->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
    $modo->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');
    $modo->removeDecorator('Label');
    $modo->addMultiOptions(array('Activo' => 'Activo', 'Passivo' => 'Passivo'));

    $estado = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('estado');
    $estado->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
    $estado->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');
    $estado->removeDecorator('Label');
    $estado->addMultiOptions(array('Activada' => 'Activada', 'Desactivada' => 'Desactivada','Blacklist'=>'Blacklist'));

    $cliente=new Zend_Form_Element_Select('cliente');
    $cliente->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
    $cliente->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');
    $cliente->removeDecorator('Label');
    $client = new Application_Model_Clientes();
    $cliente->addMultiOption(0, 'Please select...');
    foreach ($client->fetchAll() as $oCountry) {
        $cliente->addMultiOption($oCountry['id_cliente'], $oCountry['nome']);
    }


    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
    $submit->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
    $submit->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');
    $submit->removeDecorator('Label');

    $this->addElements(array(
        $name,
        $descricao,
        $modo,
        $estado,
        $cliente,

        $submit
    ));

}
```

the code for the view-add.phtml

```
<?php if($this->success): ?>
<script>
    window.parent.reloadGrid();
    window.parent.showMsgFromIframe('Utilizador adicionada com sucesso');
    window.parent.closeDialog();
</script>
<?php exit; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($this->hasError): ?>
<div class="albox errorbox" style="margin:15px 10px 15px 0 !important;z-index: 690;">
    <b>Erro :</b> <?php echo $this->errorMessage; ?> 
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="simplebox grid740" style="padding-bottom:0 !important; width:680px !important;">

<form action="" method="post" name="form2" id="form3">


    <div class="st-form-line" style="z-index: 350;">    
        <span class="st-labeltext">Nome:</span> 
        <?php echo $this->form->getElement('nome'); ?> 
        <div class="clear" style="z-index: 340;"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="st-form-line" style="z-index: 350;">    
        <span class="st-labeltext">Descrição:</span>    
        <?php echo $this->form->getElement('descricao'); ?>
        <div class="clear" style="z-index: 340;"></div>
    </div>









    <div class="st-form-line" style="z-index: 350;">    
        <span class="st-labeltext">Cliente:</span>  
        <?php echo $this->form->getElement('cliente'); ?>
        <div class="clear" style="z-index: 340;"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="st-form-line" style="z-index: 350;">    
        <span class="st-labeltext">Modo:</span> 
        <?php echo $this->form->getElement('modo'); ?>
        <div class="clear" style="z-index: 340;"></div>
    </div>


 <!-- Add a <div> element where the tree should appear: -->
 <div class="st-form-line" style="z-index: 350;">   
        <span class="st-labeltext">Localização:</span>
        //javascript code
        <script type="text/javascript">
var t=-1;

$(function(){
    // Attach the dynatree widget to an existing <div id="tree"> element
    // and pass the tree options as an argument to the dynatree() function:
    $("#tree").dynatree({
        initAjax: {
    url: "/locais/tree"
    },
    onActivate: function(node) {
  t=node.data.key;
  }, 

    });

});

</script>
        <div id="tree"> </div>-->intruction for the tree
        <div class="clear" style="z-index: 340;"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="button-box" style="z-index: 460;">
        <input type="submit" class="st-button" value="Criar utilizador" id="button" name="button">
    </div>

</form>
</div>
```

In the moment the tree doesnt show...what should i do..
thanks..
Hugo Silva

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was simple, i was missing the jquery libraries in the layout.

here it is the layout code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/theme/style/reset.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/theme/style/root.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/theme/style/grid.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/theme/style/typography.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/theme/style/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/theme/style/jquery-plugin-base.css"    />

      <script type="text/javascript" src="/theme/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/theme/js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js">    </script>
     <!--dynatree-->

<script src='/dynatree/jquery/jquery.cookie.js' type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/dynatree/src/skin/ui.dynatree.css'>
<script src='/dynatree/src/jquery.dynatree.js' type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body style="background:#fff;">

    <!--CONTENT-->
    <?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
    <!--//CONTENT-->

</body>
</html>
```